# Django login lost during redirect from IFRAME.

Tags: django, authentication

I have got IFRAME with login screen for design reasons. 
And when user logged in I trigger the parent redirect to '/my_app/welcome/' using redirect.html.
After redirect user becomes not logged in. I checked request.user.username in a view (for '/my_app/welcome/') 
but login was lost. Please advise how to keep it logged in ?

File views.py:

```
def login(request, template_name):
username = password = ''

if request.POST:
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    request.user = user

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:

            return TemplateResponse(request, 'accounts/redirect.html', {'redirect_url':'/my_app/welcome/'})

return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

File redirect.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.top.location.href = '{{ redirect_url }}';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when running two django projects on the same domain, albeit with different ports. I fixed it by starting one project from localhost:9000 and the other from 127.0.0.1:8000 . When I ran them both from 127.0.0.1 , they both lost login .

Answer (score -2):

You need add

```
auth_login(request, user)
```

after  `if user.is_active:`

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure why you think that simply assigning the user to `request.user` is enough to log them in. It isn't, because it doesn't do anything like setting the session cookie.

The correct way to log a user in, as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests) explains, is to call the appropriately-named `login` function . You probably want to call your view function something different to avoid name confusion.